# Why does my VBA code show when my module is running?

Tags: excel, vba

I created VBA project/modules in my workbook.  I've assigned to a button on worksheet to submit.  My VBA codes shows on the screen when the user clicks the button and disappears when process is complete.  I've tried hiding the Developer tab, and also tried password protected the project.  It still shows.  How do I suppress this???

No errors - just shows code.

Comment: Is the VBE showing for just the duration that the code is running (ie likely just a fraction of a second, depending on your code) and then immediately disappearing or is the VBE appearing and code execution stops until you take some action (F5 etc)? Either way, it might help to show your code (as text) in the question. You could also try removing the button and adding a new one (and assigning the macro/code to it) to see if that makes a difference (there's no obvious reason it should ... but it's the first thing I'd try).

Comment: Is shows while the code is running and disappears after.